# Googe Cloud Function Error: Node is either not visible or not an HTMLElement

Tags: google-cloud-functions, puppeteer

I have wrote a google cloud function using inline editor. I cannot see which line is throwing the error "Node is not visible or not an HTML Element" I have read through some of the other people's posts and tried the solutions which they suggested. But have not resolved the problem yet.

Is there a way to see which line throws error on google cloud online editor?
Can someone see what could be wrong with this cloud function?

```
exports.searchBing = async (req, res) => { 
    let {browser, page} = await openConnection();

  try {
    await page.goto('https://www.bing.com', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});

    page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout( 90000 );
    //await page.setViewport({width: 1024, height: 1600});

    //await page.waitFor('input[name=q]');
    await page.waitForSelector('input[name="q"]');

    var searchString = 'Hello';

    // Type search term into the search bar
    await page.type('input[name="q"]', searchString);

    try {
      await page.click('input[type="submit"]');
    } catch(error) {}
    await page.waitFor(3000);
    await page.click('input[type="submit"]');

    await page.waitForNavigation();
    await page.waitForSelector('h2 a');

    var html = await page.content();
    var results = processPage(html);

    res.status(200).send(results);


  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err.message);
  } finally {
    await closeConnection(page, browser);
  }
```

Comment: I am not sure but maybe you need to uncomment `setViewport`? Also check [this articel](https://medium.com/bluekiri/gain-web-performance-insights-with-gcp-cloud-functionsand-puppeteer-34778473f2e2) if you haven;t yet, might give you some insights on the issue.

Comment: Uncommenting setViewport does not solve the problem so I had commented to figure out where else the error is coming from.